# Why my redux state is null but in console everything is working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to make todo app but,
Every time I input something, my redux developer tools shows an '' (empty string)

**my reduce look like this**

```
const TodoReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD_TODO':
           return {
               ...state,
               todoList: [...state.todoList, action.item]
           }
    }
}

export default TodoReducer;
```

**my action**

```
export const addTodo = () => {
    return {
        type: 'ADD_TODO',
        item: ''
    }
}
```

**and the App.js**

```
function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');

  const todoList = useSelector(state => state.todoList)

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const addHandler = () => {
    console.log(`adding ${input}`)
    dispatch(addTodo({
      item: input
  }))
    setInput('');
  }
  

  return (
    <div>
        <p>TODO</p>
        <p>{todoList}</p>
        <input type="text"
        value={input}
        onChange={e=> setInput(e.target.value)}
        />

        <button type="button" onClick={addHandler}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

thank you in advance. any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to pass the item as an input to the action and return

Change:

```
export const addTodo = () => {
    return {
        type: 'ADD_TODO',
        item: ''
    }
}
```

To:

```
export const addTodo = (item) => {
    return {
        type: 'ADD_TODO',
        item: item
    }
}
```

And

Change

```
        <p>{todoList}</p>
```

To

```
        <p>
            {Array.isArray(todoList) &&
                todoList.map((item, itemIndex) => (
                    <div key={itemIndex}>{item}</div>
                ))}
        </p>
```

Comment: thank you for step by sir, but the result is error, it says :  Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {item}).

Comment: You can't just give a string array to be rendered. issue is `<p>{todoList}</p>`. Update it as given in the updated answer

Comment: @HutapeaDollyton, check the updated answer